# How to prove $ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(A_{2n} - A_{n}) $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let's say that N is a universal group. For every $n \in N$ marked that $ A_n = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\} $. For each of the groups the following, determine whether they are equal or all of the groups $N, N \setminus \{0\}, \varnothing $

1) $$ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty(A_{2n} - A_{n}) $$

2) $$ \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_{n}^c $$

3) $$ \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty A_{n}^c $$

How to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try using the following facts (try to prove them yourself as well):

- $0 \in A_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (Q1 and Q2)
- $n \in A_{2(n-1)}$ for $n \geq 1$ (Q1)
- $n \notin A_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 1$ (Q1 and Q2)
- $n \in A_n \Rightarrow n \notin A_n^c$ (Q3)